# Error with Template Tags: Invalid Block Tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to use a slightly different output template for UpdateView as compared to CreateView and I'm using this template code to remove the password fields in UpdateView

My template code is as follows:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div id="{{ field.auto_id }}_container">
{{ field.help_text }}
<div>
{% if customuser.id and field.label != 'Create your password' or
customuser.id and field.label != 'Confirm your password' %}

{{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}

{% else %}

{{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}

{% endif %}
</div>
<div id="{{ field.auto_id }}_errors">
{{ field.errors }}
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And I get the error Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Is that your actual code? That doesn't look bad.

Comment: I dont see the point of the if..else here. It is doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent Django, https://github.com/django/django/commit/4aa97f5c18 introduced an {% empty %} block, allowing you to write

```
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    ...
 {% empty %}
   No athletes
{% endfor %}
```

Useful when the something that you want to do involves iterating over a non-empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break line inside a `{% if ... %}` template tag (or any tag, actually). You should have it all in one line:

```
{% if customuser.id and field.label != 'Create your password' or customuser.id and field.label != 'Confirm your password' %}
```